# How to find pairs whose sum is already exist in array?

Tags: c, nested-loops

Let's say the user inputs 6 integers in an array with a loop.

user input: 1 3 4 5 2 2

The result should be 3, because:

1. 1+3=4
2. 1+4=5
3. 1+2=3

You don't need to count pairs if the result already exists, so you don't need to count 2+2=4 because 4 already exists from 1+3=4.

So far I am only capable find which pairs whose result already exists.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int n,n2,num[201];
    scanf("%d",&n);getchar();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        int count=0;
        
        scanf("%d",&n2);getchar();
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++){
            scanf("%d",&num[j]);getchar();
        }
        
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++){
            for(int k=j+1;k<n2;k++){
                for(int l=0;l<n2;l++){
                    if(num[j]+num[k]==num[l]){
                        
                        count++;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        printf("\n%d",count);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code.  If you run this code, the result will be 7 because:

- ( 1, 3 ) sum = 4
- ( 1, 4 ) sum = 5
- ( 1, 2 ) sum = 3
- ( 1, 2 ) sum = 3
- ( 3, 2 ) sum = 5
- ( 3, 2 ) sum = 5
- ( 2, 2 ) sum = 4

So the sums are 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4. It should be only count 4, 5, and 3.

PS: n = the number of test cases, n2 = the length of the array, num = the array.

Comment: So you need to deduplicate the output. Store all sums in an array, deduplicate it, print it.

Comment: Keep a record of which sums have been found in an array.  Before printing a new sum, check whether it has been printed before.  If so, don't print it.  If not, print it and add the new sum to the list.  Consider the merits of sorting the array before scanning for sums.

Comment: how do you do that? I tried using `if(a[num[l]]==1) continue; else a[num[l]]==1; count++;` but the online judge decline my answer, so I thought there must be a better way to do that. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: `int sumsfound[201]; int numfound = 0; int newsum = …; bool found = false; for (int i = 0; i < numfound; i++) { if (newsum == sumsfound[i]) { found = true; break; } } if (!found) { printf(…); sumsfound[numfound++] = newsum; }`

Comment: but, how do you store the result in an array? @Cheatah

Answer (score 1):

In one comment, I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328282/how-to-find-pairs-whose-sum-is-already-exist-in-array/74333419#comment131221194_74328282):

> Keep a record of which sums have been found in an array. Before printing a new sum, check whether it has been printed before. If so, don't print it. If not, print it and add the new sum to the list.

The references to 'print it' should be 'count it', but otherwise it gives a simple way of dealing with the 'no repeat sums' problem.

The code in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328282/how-to-find-pairs-whose-sum-is-already-exist-in-array-c-language?noredirect=1#comment131223120_74328282) was moderately accurate, only omitting the necessary zeroing of the `sumsfound` array.  And it needed to be integrated into the framework of your program.

You should be using/writing more functions than you are.

This code checks that `scanf()` works (using a function to report an error and exit if it fails).  It reduces the scope of variables.  It terminates the output with a newline and doesn't prefix it with a newline.  It doesn't check that the value entered for `n2` is small enough (201 or less).  Ideally, you should reject 0 or negative values too — the code won't break if `n2` is 0 or negative, but the user may be a bit surprised.  Similarly with `n` entered as 0 or a negative number; there is no positive value of `n` that will cause crashes, but boredom might set in if the value is larger than, say, 10.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static _Noreturn void err_scanf(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to read an integer value\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        err_scanf();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int n2;
        int num[201];

        if (scanf("%d", &n2) != 1)
            err_scanf();
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", &num[j]) != 1)
                err_scanf();
        }

        int sumsfound[201] = { 0 };
        int numfound = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n2; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < n2; l++)
                {
                    if (num[j] + num[k] == num[l])
                    {
                        int newsum = num[l];
                        bool found = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < numfound; i++)
                        {
                            if (newsum == sumsfound[i])
                            {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!found)
                        {
                            count++;
                            sumsfound[numfound++] = newsum;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When run with the input numbers `1 6 1 3 4 5 2 2`, it correctly produces the answer `3`.  When run with the input numbers `1 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, it correctly produces the answer `6`:

- 1 + 2 = 3
- 1 + 3 = 4
- 1 + 4 = 5
- 1 + 5 = 6
- 1 + 6 = 7
- 1 + 7 = 8

and all the other pairs add up to one of these 6 values (or add up to a number that's too big).